# Function with a callback

Tags: javascript

Learning javascript and wanted to get more clarity regarding callbacks.

In the following code snippet,

```
function do_a( callback ){
    // if callback exist execute it
    callback && callback();
}

function do_b(){
  console.log( 'do_b executed' );
}
 //one way
do_a( function(){
  do_b();
});

//other way
do_a(do_b);
```

Is there a difference between the two ways the do_a() is called. One passes a pointer to the do_b function, the other passes a function which executes the do_b function. All the examples i've seen use the first way. Is that more preferred style wise?

Comment: Both are working, but of course the second one is simpler

Comment: In this example, no - in more complex code, potentially - it depends really on how much control you want over `this`.

Comment: Instead of concentrating on callbacks, you should maybe focus more on `Promise`s, which can replace callbacks and make your code more readable

Comment: @baao I don't think callbacks are "going away" anytime soon . . . synchronous callbacks like you see with higher-order array functions (`Array#filter`, `Array#reduce`, etc.) won't be any less obsolete when Promise support becomes ubiquitous. Still a useful skill to learn!

Comment: For the record, promises are callbacks, just structured in a way that you don't get a pyramid of doom by chaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way just creates an extra anonymous function that calls the second function. This is useful if you want to perform actions before or after calling the callback, e.g.

```
do_a( function(){
    console.log("I'm going to call the second function...");
    do_b();
    console.log("Second function is done.");
});
```

Otherwise, I can't see any point in this extra function and the second way is better.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to pass it as an argument. Directly call it.

```js
function abc(){
a = "function abc";
console.log(a);
cde();
console.log(a);
}
function cde(){
a="function cde";
}

abc();
```